# Can anyone suggest the time complexity of the following code

Tags: java

```
public void computeDifference(){
int i=0,j=0;maximumDifference=0;
for (i=0;i < elements.length;i++){
    for (j=i+1;j < elements.length;j++){
        maximumDifference = (Math.abs(elements[j]-elements[i]) > maximumDifference)? Math.abs(elements[j]-elements[i]):maximumDifference;
```

What will be the time complexity of this code ?

Comment: O(n^2). With n the number of elements.

Comment: How many times does each line run?

Answer (score 0):

It would be `O(n^2)`. Because the inner loop runs `n-1` times to `1` time because of the outer loop(Outer loop runs `n` times). Therefore,

```
(n-1) + (n-2) + (n-3) + .... + 1 = n*(n+1)/2
```

So the inner statement runs approx. `n^2/2 + n/2` times. So the upper bound is `O(n^2)`. Where `n` is number of elements.